# Limit(disable days buttons) bootstrap-datepicker calendar date(date_stop can't be < date_start)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

How can I limit(disable days buttons) bootstrap-datepicker(**not jQuery Datapicker**) calendar date in this way:

`id_date_stop` can't be < `id_date_start` so

if I select `date_start` as
**06-05-2016**, `date_stop` can't be earlier than **06-05-2016**.

It can be 
from 06-05-2016 to 10-05-2016(todays date).

my html:

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-end-date="0d">
    <input id="id_date_start" name="data_start" type="text">
    <div class="input-group-addon"></div>
</div>
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-end-date="0d">
    <input id="id_date_stop" name="date_stop" type="text">
    <div class="input-group-addon"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery combined with the methods available from [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html) to set the start and end dates.

Sample code would look like this

```
    $('#id_date_start').datepicker({autoClose: true}).on('changeDate',function(e) {

    $('#id_date_stop').datepicker({autoClose: true}).datepicker('setStartDate', e.date)
    .datepicker('setEndDate', new Date());

  })
```

This code will set a start date for the 'date_stop' datepicker based on your start date selected, and will set the end date to today's date.

I am using the line `$('#id_date_start').datepicker({autoClose: true})` before the method calls, to ensure that the datepicker object is initialized. This will ensure that the methods will fire correctly.

Here is a sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wp6k2vp/).